# how to show the line at the time of tableview edit?

Tags: iphone, tableview

I have a problem, how i can show the line between check mark and move at the time of  tableview edit. like same as in below image.

[image]

explain the process or else if possible please send me to example code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Look at this :

Declare BOOL checkMark; in .h 
check its value.

```
// This all code in Cell For Row At IndexPath :

for (UIView *ObView in [cell.contentView subviews])

{

    [ObView removeFromSuperview];
}

if(checkMark == YES)  // you can check here by imdexPath.row.

{
     UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,5,150,30)];
    lbl.text = @"";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

    UIImageView *CheckImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,5,20,20)];
    CheckImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:CheckImage];

    UIImageView *BarImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(185,5,0.5,30)];
    BarImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:BarImage];

    UIImageView *tblImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,5,20,20)];
    tblImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tblImage];
}
else
{
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,5,150,30)];
    lbl.text = @"";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

    UIImageView *tblImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,5,20,20)];
    tblImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tblImage];
}
```

Note: frames are temporary.

Answer (score 1):

SO you basically have a `tableView` and you want to add that image "|" in your `tableViewCell`  when you are editing.

I would assume you already have `editingEnabled` for your tableView, and you will need to implement

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate

  {

   if (editing) {
             // Configure self.tableView and individual cells and add the "|" as a subView. 
             // It will all be tricky, and you should be able to logically place the vertical bar
             // But whatever you want to be in your EDIT mode, you will have to configure it here.
    } else {
          // Re-configure and implement the 'correct' cells back to normal tableView
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView with 1px as width and grey as backgroundColor, and add this to the right of check mark should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you Edit option is an image then you can do the code like below to show a line.

**Steps**

1] First import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

2] set border width and border color property of your Edit image.

```
[editImageView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];

[editImageView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];

//If you putting a button for edit then also you can set the same. Just replace the editImageView with your editButton
```

Hope you get exact you want!:)

Answer (score 0):

Take uiimageview in table cell and set its width to 1. Set height according to your tablename.cell.height.

It will definitely solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your tableview cell.Just add the subviews at the time of cell creation and put it hidden untill click on edit button.